# How can I manipulate RenderBody to format a tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 targeting .NET Framework 4

I've been asked at short notice to support an MVC application and I don't have a lot of time to learn MVC (I've done a lot of ASPX, but no MVC).

The application generates some HTML used in a corporate intranet.  It's really simple - the content has been refined until it's just a single image, which changes monthly.

Here's the cshtml

```
    @model MYMVCAPP.Models.Notice
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>    
    </head>
    <body id="content" >     
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
    </html>
```

When the page is rendered, the viewsource looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
        <title>TEST</title>    
    </head>
    <body id="content" >     

    <p>
    <img alt="" src="http://localhost:57223/Images/Content/3.jpg " />
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, I need to add some attributes to the image tag, so that it looks like this:

```
    <img border="none" src="http://localhost:57223/Images/Content/3.jpg" style="position: fixed; margin: 0px auto; min-height: 100%; height: 100%; right: 0px; left: 0px" />
```

Is there any way to intercept the call to @RenderBody() and manipulate the formation of the tag?  I've tried

```
    <img border="none" src=@RenderBody() style="position: fixed; margin: 0px auto; min-height: 100%; height: 100%; right: 0px; left: 0px" />
```

But that didn't work :(

Many thanks

Edward

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a style for it?

```
#content + p + img {
   position: fixed; 
   margin: 0px auto; 
   min-height: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
   right: 0px; 
   left: 0px
}
```